# AWS eb deploy doesn't show changes I made on the css file

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Here is the current setup for the website I'm working on right now:

2 Git Branches:
Test_branch (newly created for the purposes of development)
Master (established for production)

1 EB environment
Production

I made a couple of style changes on the scss file related to a wordpress site page being developed. After precompiling the stages, I pushed it to the Test_branch by git checkout. Next, I pushed my changes on the AWS production environment (I had to recently remove the cloned dev environment since it wasnt behaving according to expectations) which was originally based on the git repo master branch.

After pushing the changes, I purged the cache and looked into the page that I was expecting the changes to occur. However, changes were not dislaying accordingly. I even checked the application versions to determine if the changes I made were there and the downloaded application version had the changes. It just doesn't show on the website's page. When I check the browser console, it doesn't show the styles I applied to either.

So, the question i have is, does the eb environment only take changes if applied on the master branch? If this is the case, should I just merge the test branch to master or just checkout to master branch, push my changes and deploy. I'd have thought that it wouldn't matter which branch is being used as long as I do 'eb use ' before deploying the code.

Comment: You can add some param in css file ex:style.css?date

Comment: Hi @vadivel a. Thanks for the suggestion. I'm a bit confused on what would this do for the file though. Can you explain what this solution does?

Comment: The eb environment takes changes from whatever branch you deploy from. It absolutely does not have to be from the master branch. Double check the application version list: from Elastic Beanstalk, click on the drop-down with the name of your application, select Application Versions, and make sure your production environment is listed under the commit that has that last change.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I had to upload my theme files via W3Total Cache Plugin's CDN option and then purge the cache to properly view the changes implemented.